# Apache keep shutting down by itself with no log error

Tags: apache

My apache server keep shutting down by itself. When I check my error logs, I can see 15 files names like this

```
error.log.$NUMBER$.gz
```

The content of every error.log file is the following :

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29495] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 29495] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29495] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

I can restart apache with no problem but i know in a few days it will shutdown again...

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a normal restart due to eg. log rotation.

Comment: Yes but in fact it says restart but it does not restart it's just shutting down..

Comment: yo should still have some reason logged. As per your log's name, your system might be somoe Debian core, in which it should be logged in /var/log/system or /var/log/messages if it's RHEL.
Did you try to track down which job sends it to a graceful restart? I'd look in crontabS, or /etc/logrotate.d
Does it have any output in /var/log/cron* ?

Comment: I search in the places you advised me but i found nothing revelant... So i decided to disable apache2 log rotation by renaming apache2 to apache2.old, i see if it solved in a week

Comment: Can you paste the content of apache2 in logrotate.d?